# How to migrate Managed Metadata Store?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, managed-metadata, migration, content-migration

I need to migrate Managed Metadata Store from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013 environment. What are the check-list, I need to prepare or what are the point I need to remember/cater or what I need to ask my client before migration of Managed Metadata Store from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013 (as I know the direct migration is not possible from 2007 to 2013)?

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Managed metadata was introduced in 2010, not in 2007? Do you plan to migrate a custom metadata store?

Comment: Yes, very true. Actually, my client wants to migrate SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013 and will also involve migration of managed metadata store. What I need to ask/query my client before taking over the project. Please help...

Comment: The first thing I'd ask is how the hell they got the managed metadata store in SharePoint 2007... if they are migrating from 2007 to 2013, then they shouldn't have the MM service to migrate. Install from scratch.